# How to assign unique index value to array objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am using following function to add index to each array object but all id get same value when I check console.log

```
var foo = [...this.props.articleList];
foo.forEach(function(row, index) {
row.id = index+1;
});
console.log(foo);
```

I want something like this =>

> [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, id: 1], [{…}, {…},
>   {…}, {…}, id: 2], [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, id: 3]

but it is returning

> [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, id: 3], [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, id:
>   3], [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, id: 3]

Comment: I'd guess that each object in the array is actually a reference to the *same object* in memory, can you post more of the code so we have a [MCVE]?

Comment: actually its json data coming from reducer , i want to set in reducer only. in reducer . here is a reducer code
    case types.SOMETHING:
   var foo = [...state.List, action.payload]
  
   foo.forEach(function(row, index) {
   row.index = index+1;
   });
  return {  ...state,List: foo }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to stem from handling `foo` and subsequently manipulating `row.id` in a mutative manner.

The solution is to leverage a strategy commonly referred to as cloning.

Tools such as [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) tend to be useful for this.

See below for a practical example.

```
case types.SOMETHING: 
    return {...state, List: [...state.List, action.payload].map((row, index) => ({...row, index}))}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could user `array.map` as follows

```
var foo = [...this.props.articleList];
foo = foo.map(function(row, index) {
row.id = index+1
return row;
});
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The below two solutions would work

```
     const foo = [...this.props.articleList];
     const articles = foo.map((row, index) => (
             row.id = index+1;
     ));
    console.log(articles);
```

Or

```
     const foo = [...this.props.articleList];
     const articles = foo.map((row, index) => {
            return row.id = index+1;
     });
    console.log(articles);
```